# How to overload operator [] for dynamic matrix to return a value!? C++

Tags: c++

```
class matrix {
public:
  int **A;
  int nrColoane;
  int nrLinii;

 public:        
     int& operator[] (int nrLinii, int nrColoane);
};
```

Comment: It is common practice to use the function call operator instead since it can take multiple arguments.

Comment: To do this for 2d matrix and operator [] you need to return what is known as a proxy object. It contains a pointer to the original object and the specified row. Its operator [] will then retrieve the value for the column. But it's simpler to use operator (). Ps using a 1d vector for your data and the index calculation `x + y * width` is more efficient.

Comment: @Neil: Please, comments are second-class citizens and can be deleted at any time so putting this wisdom in a comment is utterly pointless. Write an _answer_!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible. The common way to solve your problem is to overload operator ().

```
class Matrix {
    public:
        int& operator () (int i, int j);
};
```

Comment: It is possible, just tricky.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, it's common to solve the problem using `operator()`. An alternative is to still use `operator[]` taking one argument, but return an object that represents a row (and keeps a reference to the original object). Then the row object will again implement `operator[]` and return the actual value.